# Is it possible to have an application that uses both V2 and V3

Tags: quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

There are some entities that are supported in V2 that are not yet supported in V3.  Is there any guidance on how to use both V2 and V3 in the same app?

Answer (score 1):

A hybrid model for v2 and v3 is not supported as the assembly names might conflict in the same  project. You can use 2 different projects in same namespace to access v2 and v3 separately.

Comment: Karen, at the application level it is fine to use both services in your app. However as Nimisha mentioned you should keep them separated in code to avoid conflicts.